# Spring Security adding security for only one path

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My use case is simple but could not find an example. I want to allow all my  endpoints excluding only one path which will require basic authentication who has `USER` role. How to do it with Spring Security's antmatchers? I tried something like below but I get   `401 Unauthorized` in all requests.

```
httpSecurity
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
```

Comment: What if you remove .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER") ?

Comment: Kindly share the entire configuration code